# Insert multiple lines into file from position without overwriting the previous inserted line

Tags: c#, wpf, file-handling

I want to insert multiple "items" into a list using a foreach loop(looping over a list). Now I want to insert the lines as a `<td>` element. But by specifying the index at the position I want to insert the line, the previous one gets overwritten. How can I add a line at position and then add the rest afterwards without overwriting the previously added line

```
private void Create_Driver_Report(string npcName)
{

    var fileName = Get_Path("Driver_Reports.html");
    var endTag = npcName;
    var lineToAdd = "<!--New Line Here-->";
    var htmlContent = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList();
    var index = htmlContent.FindIndex(x => x.Contains(lineToAdd));
           
    htmlContent.Insert(index + 1, endTag);          
    File.WriteAllLines("drivers.html", htmlContent);
}
```

How I want to do it in theory

```
foreach (Drivers item in drivers)
{
    Create_Driver_Report($"<td>{item.Driver_ID}</td>");
    Create_Driver_Report($"<td>{item.Driver_Name}</td>");
    Create_Driver_Report($"<td>{item.Vehicle_ID}</td>");
    Create_Driver_Report($"<td>{item.Company_ID}</td>");
    Create_Driver_Report($"<td>{item.Company_Name}</td>");                
}
```

Comment: `Insert` doesn't overwrite. However, you are inserting to the same exact index every time, so perhaps that is why you think it is overwriting the line. If you simply increment your index it will insert after the previous.

Comment: I know thats why it happens, but if I used the foreach loop, the last property only is added, so thats why I asked, I want to add all of them at once

Comment: This is confused. Could you explain what is exactly your purpose? For instance could you explain the role of the two files you mention: `Driver_Reports.html` and `drivers.html`?  Could you elaborate the role of the placeholders `"<!--New Line Here-->"`?

Comment: So driver_reports.html is a template I'm using for a pdf document, drivers.html is the "updated template" and then "<!--New Line Here-->" is sort of the index at which I want to insert the new lines into

Comment: Is `Driver_Reports.html` some sort of a template that you fill, and `drivers.html` the destination file that will hold a collection of drivers made from that template?

Comment: Yes exactly, its for an assignment for school, a report for everything is a requirement

Comment: Please edit your question so that it is more clear. You will have more chances to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: How is my question unclear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239217/discussion-between-laurent-gabiot-and-pureware-legends-of-gaming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the ToString() method or create a new one.
If you always want to insert the same properties, seems unnecessary to invoke the `Create_Driver_Report` over and over again.

```
public override String ToString() {
        return
            $"<td>{this.Driver_ID}</td>\n" +
            $"<td>{this.Driver_Name}</td>\n" +
            $"<td>{this.Vehichle_ID}</td>\n" +
            $"<td>{this.Company_ID}</td>\n" +
            $"<td>{this.Company_Name}</td>";
    }
```

and you can invoke it like:

```
foreach (Drivers item in drivers) {
    Create_Driver_Report(item.ToString());
}
```

Edit:
Option 1:
Use LINQ Select() and List.InsertRange()

```
public String ToHtmlRow() {
    return
        $"<tr><td>{this.Driver_ID}</td><td>{this.Driver_Name}</td><td>{this.Vehichle_ID}</td><td>{this.Company_ID}</td><td>{this.Company_Name}</td></tr>";
}

{
  IEnumerable<string> lines = drivers.Select(driver => driver.ToString())
  Create_Driver_Report(lines);
}

static void Create_Driver_Report(IEnumerable<string> lines) {
    var fileName = Get_Path("Driver_Reports.html");
    var lineToAdd = "<!--New Line Here-->";
    var htmlContent = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList();
    var index = htmlContent.FindIndex(x => x.Contains(lineToAdd));
    
    htmlContent.InsertRange(index + 1, lines);
    File.WriteAllLines("drivers.html", htmlContent);
}
```

Option 2:
You just add all of the rows you want and you call the `Create_Driver_Report` only once.

```
List<String> toAdd = new List<String>();
foreach (Drivers item in drivers) {
    toAdded.Add(item.ToHtmlRow());
}

Create_Driver_Report(String.Join("\n", toAdd));
```

Comment: Would this still work if I add 2 drivers in the list with different information

Comment: Have to modify a little bit, but yes. It would work.

Comment: What would need to be modified? I want to eliminate having to write redundant code

Comment: I appreciate your answer, It works flawlessly